# descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"/"beforeDescendants" seem to do nothing

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to create a list item that contains both an EditText and a Spinner. The list item has to also be clickable. The list item could detect clicks until I added the Spinner. I found that to allow the list item to continue being clickable I had to set `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"`. This allowed the list item to be clickable again, but now the EditText is no longer focusable and therefore cannot be modified by the user.
The solution I thought lied in using either `android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"` or `android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"` but neither of these solutions work.
How can I allow the user to edit the EditText, click the list item, and use a Spinner?

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

    <EditText        
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText"/>
    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:toEndOf="@id/editText"
        android:alignParentEnd="true"
        android:id="@+id/spinner"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: hello,have you found your solution or not?

Comment: No, I have not figured out how to do it. I can at best trigger two of the three listeners. I feel like setting the focusability to afterDescendants should do the trick, but it acts no differently than beforeDescendants and neither of them work.